# What causes the undistorted propagation of picosecond THz pulses not to be possible for circular waveguides?

Tags: optics, waves, frequency, waveguide

When reading about the concept of *circular waveguides*, I came across the following statement that I am struggling to undertand.

*"(...) for circular waveguides the undistorted propagation of picosecond THz pulses was shown not to be possible, because of the extreme dispersion near the cutoff frequencies overlapped by the pulse bandwidth covering many octaves in the frequency."* [1]

**What causes this dispersion near the cutoff frequencies?**

**How does the overlapping of the pulse bandwidth with the dispersion near the cutoff frequencies cause distortion in the propagation?**

---

[1] - [Terahertz Waveguides by G. Gallot et. al (2020)](https://www.osapublishing.org/josab/abstract.cfm?uri=josab-17-5-851)

Comment: Recall the Lorentz oscillator model as applied to absorption and the associated dispersion near various transitions. Now consider how a high-bandwidth signal will behave when it sees lots of dispersion - the wave envelope coming out of such a region will look little like the wave that went in.

Comment: Is the following what you mean: the waves leaving the waveguide would not look like the input waves because the different frequencies would disperse differently? I still don't quite understand the relation to the "spring-like" electron oscillation presented by the Lorentz oscillator model. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Now, the Lorentz model more generally implies that when you have an absorption feature you will have dispersion around it - that is all. It is more general than electrons on springs as in introductory texts.

Comment: For reference,  red light is roughly  460 THz .